# Sort data with a loop to find the nearest restaurant to a user

Tags: node.js, mongodb, loops

I have restaurant geocoordinates stored in a MongoDB database.

Now I need to create a loop to get all the restaurant geocoordinates with user geocoordinates to get the nearest 5 restaurants. I don't know how to loop and match the geocoordinates with the user.

I want to get exactly 5 restaurants nearby me because the Google place API is integrated in the frontend so I can only get the geocoordinates on which I need to match to get the exact restaurant nearby me.

```
nearby_restro: (req, res) => {var user_id = req.user;var reqdata = req.body;var lat = reqdata.lat;
var long = reqdata.long; 
 locationModel.find({
"loc": {$near: [longitude = long, latitude = lat]}}, (err, data) => {console.log(err)
console.log(data)})
model 
   userId :{  type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, auto: true},
    loc: {
      type: {
        type: String, // Don't do `{ location: { type: String } }`
        enum: ['Point'], // 'location.type' must be 'Point'
      },
      cordinates:[{
        longitude:{type:String },
        latitude:{type:String },
      }],
```

I want all the nearby restaurants of the user by using coordinates of the restro and the user in long and lat. I am using the user coordinates but this query is not working for me.

Comment: Have you considered using MongoDB geospatial search? I've worked it with and it solves this problem.
https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/fundamentals/crud/read-operations/geo/

Comment: can you please share some sample code of nodejs?

Comment: geonear is the way go forward. Read the docs to understand it further.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB Geospatial uses geoJSON. below is how the schema should look. note that the geo field was indexed using 2dsphere.

```
const productSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  geo: {
    type: {
      type: String, // Don't do `{ location: { type: String } }`
      enum: ['Point'], // 'location.type' must be 'Point'
      default: 'Point',
    },
    coordinates: [
      { type: Number },
    ],
  },
}, { timestamps: true });

productSchema.index({ geo: '2dsphere', name: 'text' });
```

to query the product collection, we'll use the MongoDB $geoNear query

```
const products = ProductModel.aggregate([
    {
      $geoNear: {
        near: { type: 'Point', coordinates: [<lat>, <lng>] },
        key: 'geo',
        distanceField: 'dist.calculated',
        spherical: true,
      },
    },
    { $limit: 10 },
  ]);
```

The distanceField will return a number showing the distance between the item and the passed coordiante.

Comment: nearby_restro: (req, res) => {
  var user_id = req.user;
  var reqdata = req.body;
  var lat = reqdata.lat;
  var long = reqdata.long;

 locationModel.find({
   "loc": {
    $near: [longitude = long, latitude = lat]
   }
  }, (err, data) => {
   console.log(err)
   console.log(data)
  })

Comment: Error response
data Aggregate {
0|app  |   _pipeline:
0|app  |    [ { '$match': [Object] },
0|app  |      { '$geoNear': [Object] },
0|app  |      { '$limit': 5 } ],
0|app  |   _model: Model { location },
0|app  |   options: {} }
0|app  | Mongoose: locations.aggregate([ { '$match': { user_type: 'vendor' } }, { '$geoNear': { near: { type: 'Point', cordinates: [ '12.214048', '82.361727' ] }, key: 'loc' } }, { '$limit': 5 } ], {})
0|app  | Mongoose: locations.find({ user_type: 'user_type' }, { projection: {} })
0|app  | data undefined